# What would be the image of $1+\pi O_K$ under the field norm?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, normed-spaces, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a $d$-degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $O_K$, unique maximal ideal $m_K$ and uniformizer $\pi$. Let $N=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}$ be the field norm.

Consider the compact open set $U=1+\pi O_K=1+\pi \mathbb{Z}_p^d$, where $d=[K: \mathbb{Q}_p]$.

**Question:**

What would be the image $N(U)$ ?

---

For any $\alpha \in K$, the norm $N(\alpha)$ is the determinant of the multiplication by $\alpha$ map $x \mapsto \alpha x$.

If $K$ is Galois extension, then $$|N(\alpha)|=\prod_{\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)}|\sigma(\alpha)|=|\alpha|^d,$$ where $|.|$ is the norm extending $|.|_p$.

Another simple case, if $U=1+p \mathbb{Z}_p$, then any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ fix it i.e., $\sigma(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)=1+p \sigma(\mathbb{Z}_p)=1+p \mathbb{Z}_p$ and therefore $$N(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)=\prod_{\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)}\sigma(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)=\prod_{\sigma \in \text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)}(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)=(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^d.$$
What is $(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^d$ ?

**Edit:** Serre's book on "Local Field" says $$N(1+\pi^n O_K) \subset 1+p^n \mathbb{Z}_p.$$
When is $N(1+\pi^n O_K) = 1+p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$ ?

But what would be the exact image $N(U)$, when $U=1+\pi O_K$ ?

I appreciate any comments. Thanks

Comment: The last equation "$=\alpha^d$" in your third-to-last line is only true iff $\alpha \in \mathbb Q_p$. -- Do you think the answer is the same for any extension of degree $d$? I would **strongly suggest** working through two examples with $d=2$ yourself, namely i) the unramified quadratic one, and ii) $K= \mathbb Q_p(\sqrt p)$. In these quadratic cases, computing the norms needs little more than basic algebra. Try these and add your results to the question. If you cannot do these two examples, then I strongly doubt you would understand an answer in the general case.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, Thanks. I have edited

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I don't think the question needs to add an explicit calculation of $N(\alpha)$ of a particular point $\alpha$  under $N$.  I need to compute $N(U)$.

Comment: But what is $N(U)$ if not the union of all $N(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in U$??? I reiterate, one will not understand an answer to this question without knowing to compute examples like the ones I mentioned, and I would like to see your attempts for that. Whether you do that by computing $N(U)$ as the union of all $N(\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in U$ or by some other method, I don't care. -- By the way $U=1+p\mathbb Z_p$ iff $K=\mathbb Q_p$. If you tried the examples, you would see that your little calculation still might have some merit, because of course every $U$ contains $1+p\mathbb Z_p$, so ...

Comment: Then again, that calculation, or more precisely the step $(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^d=1+p^d \mathbb{Z}_p$, is of course wrong in general. Maybe you should understand the structure of the multiplicative group $1+p\mathbb Z_p$ before tackling the more general case $1+\pi O_K$, and only then try your luck with norms. I guess that's why it's presented in this order in all good sources about local fields.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, well, lets conisder the unramified extension $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$ of $\mathbb{Q}_2$. The basis is $1, \frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Now you asking to calculate $N(\alpha)$. But which $\alpha$ you are talking about ?

Comment: Any $\alpha \in U$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, as $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$ is unramified $\pi=2$. So $1+2 \cdot 2=5 \in 1+\pi O_K$. So take $\alpha=5$. Now $1, \sqrt{-3}$ is a basis. So multiplication by $\alpha$ map has matrix with columns $(5, 0)^T$ and $(0, \sqrt{-3})^T$, So $N(\alpha)=5 \sqrt{-3}$. So how does it help me ?

Comment: No, $N(5)=25$ in that example, as quite generally (and you write that yourself) $N(\alpha)=\alpha^d$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb Q_p$ (which, by the way, should make it interesting to you: Have you figured out what $(1+p\mathbb Z_p)^d$ *actually* is? Hint: It depends on whether $p$ divides $d$ or not.) By the way, $p=2$ is the oddest possible choice for concrete examples of a quadratic extension. Why don't you first say $p$ is odd, assume $K=\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt D)$ unramified, and then try to correctly compute **i)** $N(1+px)$ and **ii)** $N(1+p\sqrt{D}x)$ for arbitrary $x \in \mathbb Z_p$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I just want to sort out the two things. To calculate $N(5)$, I miscalculated the column vectors. The matrix would be $5I_{2,2}$ with determinant $25$. Now $25=1+4 \cdot 6$, where $6 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. So $N(\alpha) \in 1+4 \mathbb{Z}_2$. So $N(1+\pi O_K) \subseteq 1+4 \mathbb{Z}_2$. Is there any fault ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, if we take a more interesting element say, $\alpha=1+2\sqrt{-3}$, then $N(\alpha)=1^2-2^2(-3)=1+4 \cdot 3 \in 1+4 \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, but couldn't sort out what would be $(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^d$ ? Assume $p=2$ and $d=3$, then $ p \nmid d$, then $(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^3=\{1+(x+y+z)p+(xy+yz+zx)p^2+xyzp^3~|x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}_p \}$. It can be written in more short form $(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^3=\{1+ap+bp^2+cp^3~|a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_p \}\equiv 1 \ (mod \ p)=1+p \mathbb{Z}_p$. Am I right ?

Comment: That looks good, except that you cannot conclude $N(1+\pi O_K) \subseteq 1+ 4 \mathbb Z_2$, rather the other way around ($\supseteq$). -- For the unramified extension $\mathbb Q_2(\sqrt{3})$, now take $\zeta_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and compute $N(1+2\zeta_3)$. -- Also your last comment is on the right track. If you understand *why* that can be written in the shorter form, you should be able to figure out what $(1+p\mathbb Z_p)^d$ (and hence $N(1+\pi O_k)$) is for all $d$ not divisible by $p$. (Alternatively, you can use the $p$-adic logarithm for that.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thanks. You mean $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-3})$ in your last comment ? Second, it is not clear to me how to treat $(1+p \mathbb{Z}_p)^d$ when $p \mid d$. Any help on this. How $p \mid d$ affect on the calculation ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, all $\sqrt 3$ are supposed to be $\sqrt{-3}$. As to how $p \vert d$ affects the calculation, well again try a few examples and use the binomial formula.